# Как сделать чтобы при возврате на фрагмент он не пересоздавался

Tags: android, android-fragment, activity-life-cycle

Есть фрагмент. Он добавлен в `BackStack` В `onActivityCreated` я инициализирую маленький `ImageView`, `TextView` - название и еще один `TextView` - описание.
Потом иду в сеть(вызываю метод из другого класса).
Все загружается, заполняется - нормально. При нажатии на `ImagaView` открывается другой фрагмент(увеличенная картинка).
При возврате c фрагмента с увеличенной кратинкой на предыдущий фрагмент все перезагружается: картинка, название, описание. Т.е. фрагмент, можно сказать, создается заново.
Как сделать так, чтобы фрагмент не пересоздавался, а сохранялся, и при возврате на него ничего не перезагружалось, а оставалось как было.

Отслеживал все методы жизненного цикла. Заметил, что при возврате на фрагмент не срабатывает только `onCreate`. Попробовал запихнуть весь код в него - ошибка.
Помогите вообщем.

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    Log.v("frag", "onAttach started");
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.v("frag", "onCreate started");
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.v("frag", "onCreateView started");
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.v("frag", "onActivityCreated started");
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    //здесь инициализирую вьюшки

    //а здесь иду в сеть и при загрузке ставлю во вьюшки
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Log.v("frag", "onStart started");
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.v("frag", "onResume started");
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.v("frag", "onPause started");
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Log.v("frag", "onStop started");
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    Log.v("frag", "onDestroyView started");
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.v("frag", "onDestroy started");
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    Log.v("frag", "onDetach started");
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

}

void setCurrentFragmentItemChecked () {
    Menu menu = navigation.getMenu();
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.getItem(3);
    menuItem.setChecked(true);
}
```

Comment: а вы каким способом возвращаетесь с фрагмента, где увеличенная картинка на этот фрагмент?

Comment: Кнопкой назад..

Comment: Мда)) Понятно, что не кнопкой вперёд)) Я имею в виду, стоит ли обработчик этой кнопки, и если да, что ты там пишешь, через Intent или просто finish

Comment: Нет не стоит обработчик

Comment: Попробуй обработчик навесить и `finish();` сделать.

Comment: А что это даст?

Comment: Просто финиш написать в onBackPressed?

Comment: Да, просто `finish();` перед super.onBackPressed

Comment: А он не имплементируется во фрагменте

Comment: И finish надо во фрагменте с увеличенным изображением прописывать?

Comment: Если вы самостоятельно нашли решение, оформите его, как ответ (кнопка "ответить на собственный вопрос"). Это позволит другим участникам быстрее решить аналогичную проблему.

Answer (score 0):

Если у обоих фрагментов одна активити хостинг, то попробуйте в этой активити написать следующее:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 1) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        } else {
            finish();
        }
    }
```

Таким образом, при нажатие кнопки назад, фрагмент должен восстановиться в том состояние, что и был до открытия вашей картинки в увеличенном виде.

Comment: Решил проблему)) вместо replace поставил add.

Answer (score 0):

getSupportFragmentManager.beginTransaction.add(R.id.content_frame, new Fragment2()).commit();

При нажатие на физ. кнопку back, вернутся к предыдущему фрагменту. Команда add вместо replace. Помню сам лично в свое время сутки потратил на решение этой проблемы :))