# Как не перерисовывать фрагмент при возврате на него?

Tags: android, android-fragment

Хочу добиться того, чтобы фрагмент не перерисовывался при возврате на него.

Прежде всего - я видел вопрос [Как сделать чтобы при возврате на фрагмент он не пересоздавался](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/746708/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%84%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-%d0%be%d0%bd-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%81%d1%8f) . Но ответ работает с обычными трнзакциями, но у меня в приложении navigation components и доступа к методам транзакции нет.

Делаю так:

Храню contentView внутри фрагмента, в `onCreateView` возвращаю contentView или, если он пока не создан - новый вью и присваиваю ссылку на него contentView

При возврате на фрагмент видим

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:5050)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4881)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4821)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4794)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1328)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.addAddedFragments(FragmentManager.java:2515)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2290)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2246)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2143)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$3.run(FragmentManager.java:417)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6940)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:537)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Ошибка вылезает не в нашем коде, но внутри фрамент менеджера и ч помощью логов легко убедиться, что это наши view

не беда,  делаем функцию prepareView

```
private fun prepareView(view: View?): View? =
    (view?.parent as? ViewGroup)?.removeView(view).let { view }
```

оборачиваем в неё то, что возвращается в `onCreateView` - и всё начинает работать, но через раз. И снова не беда - вызываем функцию на contentView в `onDestroyView` - работает, ура!

Однако, если открытьь следующий фрагмент и нажать назад очень быстро - ошибка вылезает снова.

Как я понимаю это происходит из за того, что всё распараллеливается на треды и removeView попросту не успевает отработать к тому времени, когда contentView пытается приаттачиться.

Кто нибудь может подсказать или посоветовать,как это можно захендлить?

Comment: А с какой целью вы хотите этого добиться? Подход с пересозданием вью для фрагментов родился не на пустом месте, нужны причина чтоб пытаться его обмануть

Comment: @СпицкоДмитрий Попробуйте представить кейс - есть список с пгинацией. Мы листаем его, доходим до третьей страницы, проваливаемся в айтем и возвращаемся назад. Не важно - толстый клиент или тонкий и берём мы этот список с сервера или локльной бд - мы оказываемся в начале списка. Когда приложение - это интернет магазин, а список товаров его ключевой компонент - думать особо не приходится. Это всего лишь один из многих кейсов, но суть в том, чтобы приходить туда откуда пришёл

Comment: Тогда действовать надо не так. Надо сохранять состояние прокрутки. Если речь про RecyclerView, например, но делается это так: Parceble savedState = ((LinearLayoutManager)list.getLayoutManager()).onSaveInstanceState() и восстанавливаете в onViewCreated вот так ((LinearLayoutManager)list.getLayoutManager()).onRestoreInstanceState(savedState). Попробуйте, может это решит вашу проблему

Comment: Проблема в том, что view пересоздаётся и у ресайклера нет лейаут менеджера

Comment: Вы же первый раз когда создаете recyclerView, то создаете и манагер. Если не создадите - recycler вообще не рабоатет. На этом этапе, если есть сохраненное состояние, передайте его манагеру. Или поставьте сохранение и восстановление состояний в onPause и onResume

Comment: @СпицкоДмитрий сейчас ресёрчу это решение. Выглядит более правильно. Только я не понимаю, onSaveInstanceState() сам по себе ничего не делает, только возвращает парселейбл. Его нужно куда то положитью. Напрашивается onSaveInstanceState фрагмента, но оно не вызывается когда фрагмент кладётся в стек, только когда новая активити стартует. А в onResume и onPause у нас нет доступа к outState

Comment: не уверен как именно действовать с переходом на другую активити... Но, например, елси указать retainInstance = true и сохранять состояние во внутреннем поле фрагмента, то оно переживает, например, смену ориентации экрана. Попробуйте так, не помню как там в стеке ведут себя retainInstance фрагменты...

Comment: @СпицкоДмитрий Новая активити и не нужна, сейчас о переходах между фрагментатми. Похоже в Android Navigation Component onSaveInstanceState не вызывается у фрагмента (

Comment: Укажите фрагменту retainInstance, сохраняйцте/загружайте в onPause и onResume. Это точно работает при переходе между фрагментами внутри одной активити

Comment: Покажите пожалуйста код onCreateView фрагмента и где вызывается. Похожая проблема была, может это оно.

Comment: @PawelShi добавил ответ ниже

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл причину происходящего - это transition. При переходе дальше по графу и последующему возврату назад анимация транзишна не успевает отработать. По этой причине у фрагмента не успевает корректно отработать onDestroyView и получаем эту ошибку, если быстро двигаемся с первого фрагмента на второй и тут же обратно.

Надо проверить как это будет работать с новым FragmentContainerView, но с обыным контейнером решение такое

```
abstract class BaseFragment : Fragment() {

    private var contentView: View? = null

    private var initialized = false

    override fun onCreateAnimation(transit: Int, enter: Boolean, nextAnim: Int): Animation? {
        return if (nextAnim <= 0)
            super.onCreateAnimation(transit, enter, nextAnim).also { initialized = true }
        else
            AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(activity, nextAnim)
                .apply {
                    setAnimationListener(object : AnimationListenerAdapter() {
                        override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animation?) {
                            super.onAnimationEnd(animation)
                            initialized = true
                        }
                    })
                }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? =
        prepareView(contentView ?: 
            createView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState))

    abstract fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) : View?

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        contentView = view
    }

    private fun prepareView(view: View?): View? =
        (view?.parent as? ViewGroup)?.removeView(view).let { view }

    // Этот метод вызывается в NavigationActivity и вызывает onBackPressed активити только если onBackPressed фрагмента возвращает true. То есть пока анимация не отработала - onBackPressed активити не вызовется
    @CallSuper
    fun onBackPressed() = initialized

}
```

Выглядит достаточно адово, но у меня наконец фабрик перестал пачками выдавать отчёты об этой ошибке. Если быть честным - он перестал их выдавать в приниципе )